# Comparing characters in strings using pointers to arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am working on an assignment to complete a function `bool isEven(char* s, char* v)`. The purpose of the function is to count the occurrence of certain letters specified (indicated by `v`) in a string (indicated by `s`). `s` and `v` are pointers to arrays holding chars.

The function returns `true` if the number of instances of letters from `v` found in `s` is even. For example, given the string `"once upon a time"` and the string of letters to be counted, like vowels, `"aeiou"`, it would return `false` because there are 7 vowels (vowels was just an example, it could be any random string of letters).

I have a variable `count` to count the instances that any letter in `v` occurs in `s`. When I run my program my count always comes back as `0`. What am I doing wrong? Could anyone tell me how to correct my code to fix this?

I tried this with nested `while` loops too and got the same thing.

```cpp
bool isEven(char* s, char* v) {
    int count = 0;
    // iterate through de-referenced strings
    for (int i = 0; *(s+i) != '\0'; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; *(v+j) != '\0'; j++) {
            if (*(s+i) == *(v+j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    // check count output
    std::cout << count;

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << count;` -- this will never be executed because of `return` statements above

Comment: you mistake an assignment operator `=` and comparison operator `==` -- should replace all `=` in `for` loops with `==` or `!=`

Comment: for (int i = 0; *(s+i) = '\0'; i++) ... I guess he meant: for (int i = 0; *(s + i) != '\0'; i++) - is not equals to.

Comment: @lenik I'll fix that - but I was testing the function without being a bool (as an int type) just to see if my counter was working I still got 0 when returning count then.

Comment: @LinuXMan yes you're right - I just fixed that but my count still returns 0.

Comment: `*(s+i) = '\0';` should change to `*(s+i) != '\0';` and `*(v+j) = '\0';` should change to `*(v+j) != '\0';`

Comment: @john you're right. I did that, though and it is still returning 0 for the count

Comment: Your code is working for me http://cpp.sh/837ti you must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @john huh that's really weird - but also great news. This problem is just to study for an exam and if it works for where you ran it then I'm gonna consider this problem done and understood! Thank you!

Comment: `*(s+i)` can be also written as `s[i]`, and the last monstrous `if` is actually `return count % 2 == 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me and probably an answer for you:

```
#include <iostream>

bool isEven(char[], char[]);

int main(void)
{
    bool flag = isEven("Hello Worldo", "aeiou");

    if (flag)
        std::cout << "Even" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not even." << std::endl;
}

bool isEven(char toCheck[], char from[])
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; toCheck[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; from[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (toCheck[i] == from[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << count << std::endl;

    return (count % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

> **Output**

```
4
Even
```

The character arrayed string `Hello Worldo` will show up `4` with `Even`, if the vowels or any entered character of `from` is found in `toCheck`, it'll count and determine if that's divisible by 2. If not, then return false (Not even), otherwise true (even).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to change the parameters from the pointers that they are, as that is what was given by the professor. But I do understand your code and see how it works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @SaraMillan Arrays are decayed to pointers to their first elements. So, `*` and `[]` are interchangeable in function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with my compiler, not the code, once I fixed the != in my for-loops, so the code here and above is correct. Thanks to everyone who took the time to try to help!

```
bool isEven(char* s, char* v) {
    int count = 0;
    // iterate through de-referenced strings
    for (int i = 0; *(s+i) != '\0'; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; *(v+j) != '\0'; j++) {
            if (*(s+i) == *(v+j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    //check count 
    std::cout << count << '\n';

    if (count % 2 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program works fine with some minor modifications to the types to avoid the warnings.

PS : I tried with latest gcc (9.3) and below is the link to the live example : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WWHecV

Answer (score -1):

Two levels of loop is O(M*N) solution. Since there are only 256 possible characters at most, usually the most optimal way is using an array of 256 integers to count occurrence of each character, and then go over characters in `v` and sum up the occurrence of these characters.

This solution only needs to go over `s` and `v` once, the complexity is O(M+N). The performance difference is significant when the input `s` is very large (for example, Harry Potter books).

```
bool isEven(char* s, char* v) {
    int counts[256];  // counter for each possible letters.
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) counts[i] = 0;
    char* p = s;
    while (*p) ++counts[static_cast<uint8_t>(*p++)];  // count occurrence of each letter.
    p = v;
    int count = 0;
    while (*p) count += counts[static_cast<uint8_t>(*p++)];  // accumulate total occurrence
    return (count % 2 == 0);
}
```